# Is there a distro that is ready to be flashed on a HDD as a complete system?

Tags: linux, distribution-choice

Because of some hardware issues, I am unable to successfully install any OS right now.

I am looking for distribution that I can flash onto the laptop HDD from another PC and run it on the faulty laptop, as if I installed it there, until I can get the laptop into service.

The only functions I need the OS to perform are web browsing and possibly some kind of text editing.

Comment: Does it have to be *flashed* or will "install it on the other PC then move the hard drive to the laptop" work (because I've moved a drive to a new laptop when the previous one died, multiple times; any modern Linux should do just fine with this)?

Comment: Hmm. This should work, I did not know this would work with Linux. I know on Windows it won't work. I will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like puppy Linux could do the trick.

Comment: I tried it right now, a few seconds after initial boot I get kernel panic.

Comment: You could install it on a USB drive and boot from there.